# Delete similar lines - PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to delete all lines that have the same first 30 characters of the line and then only to left the first line that has these characters?

Example:

```
xx2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fdsfdsfs
xx2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 43434343
```

The second should be deleted... Hope it's possible... Thanks

Comment: Anything is possible :) However this could be a *complex* problem if you are continually testing lines against previous lines.

Comment: On the shell you can do this with `uniq` very easily.

Comment: Maybe someone can use this to give me some assistance: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/remove-duplicated-lines.htm

Comment: @Kerrek SB  I need this in a php script

Comment: Okay, I edited some missing brackets in my answer just now. Good luck.

Comment: How many lines are you working with?  Are the lines stored in a file, or are they coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to deal with really large files, reading only one line at a time and writing to a temp file will consume less memory. Using a temp file and renaming it to the input file when done will do the operation atomically without losing your original file. Checking for array keys instead of values will offer fast lookup since keys are indexed. You also need to handle the edge case of a blank line returning `false` on `substr`.

```
<?php
$infile_name = "infile.txt";

$seen = array();
$infile = fopen($infile_name, "r");
if ( $infile !== false ) {
    // Temporary file to write results to
    $outfile_name = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'tmp');
    $outfile = fopen($outfile_name, "w");

    while (!feof($infile)) {
        $line = fgets($infile);
        if ( $line == '' ) {
            // blank line, just write it
            fwrite($outfile, $line);
        }
        else {
            $prefix = substr( $line, 0, 30 );

            if ( !array_key_exists($prefix, $seen) ) {
               fwrite($outfile, $line);

               // Store the prefix as a key for fast indexed lookup
               $seen[$prefix] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($infile);
    fclose($outfile);

    // Remove the old file and put the new file in its place
    unlink($infile_name);
    rename($outfile_name, $infile_name);
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but it just trades speed for space and simplicity for complexity.

Comment: Correct, but it's also safer and handles edge cases. Typically with file manipulation you are dealing with large files. Loading a large file into memory might not be a good idea - depending on your application and resources. Reading a file into an array takes memory for the original contents of the file plus the data in the array plus the size of your output array plus the size of the prefix array. So the memory need for that is 3 times the file size and then some. The memory needed for this is a little more than the length of one line plus the size of the prefix array.

Comment: fgets also handle multiple line endings without regular expressions. I would contend that this solution isn't slower at all, but is more complex.

Comment: @xander's suggestion combined with preg_replace for finding newlines works quite well with edge cases. However, I admit I may have spoke too soon (eating crow). :-) I see your point about loading large files, so I guess (as always) it depends on your needs. It's good to have to pieces of code around so that one may choose based on his/her need. +1

Comment: File access is **much** slower than memory access, especially in a loop.

Comment: Agreed. If you have smaller files, do it in memory using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$page = explode( "\n", $file );
$count = 0;
foreach( $page as $line )
{
  if( in_array( substr( $line, 0, 30 ), $search ) ){
    unset( $page[$count] );  // delete the duplicate..
  }else{
    $search[] = substr( $line, 0, 30 );
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Basically it takes a file or multi-line string and loops through file line by line. If the first 30 characters have been encountered then this deletes the line. If it has not then it is added to the list to be checked against. When it is done looping through the file there will be one instance of each unique beginning string only.
Give it a try, Good luck.

Comment: +1, excellent. I would recommend changing `$page = explode( "\n", $file );` to `$page = preg_split("%(\r\n|\r|\n)%");` in order to catch line endings from all systems.

Comment: How about `preg_split( '/[\r\n]*/', $file );` to catch all combinations.

Comment: Nevermind. Belay my last. Bad idea. :) Use @Dave's suggestion instead.

Comment: Thank you for the great help... It will help me , i will use a combination of this and the second answer :D....